How can I make my method async when it calls a library method requiring a completion?
In my app I'm using a third party library, AppGuard, to log users in. To do so the library has a method that takes a completion. Recently I got the suggestion to convert it to async/await as actors aren't compatible with the old threading practices.
Without async/await my login method looks like this:
func login() {
    // Set the necessary configuration like client ID and redirect URI.
    // The config is also loaded.

    // performs authentication request
    self.appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: scene!.keyWindow!.rootViewController!) { authState, error in
        if let authState = authState {
            self.setAuthState(authState)
            print("Got authorization tokens!")
            self.retrieveCookies()
        } else {
            print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            self.setAuthState(nil)
        }
    }
}

In an attempt to use async/await I've rewritten it to this:
func login() async {
    // Set the necessary configuration like client ID and redirect URI.
    // The config is also loaded.

    // performs authentication request
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        self.appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: scene!.keyWindow!.rootViewController!) { authState, error in
            if let authState = authState {
                self.setAuthState(authState)
                print("Got authorization tokens!")
                self.retrieveCookies()
            } else {
                print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                self.setAuthState(nil)
            }
            continuation.resume()
        }
    }
}

Is this the correct way to use async/await when making use of a method that takes a completion, a method you can't refactor as it comes from a library?
And what would be the advantages when using async/await in this case instead of keeping it in the first form?

AFAIK, this is correct if you want a func login() async {...}.
You then call it using await login(), in .task{...} for example.
Does your code work, if not can you show what errors you get.

The code works. I've tried this for another method that returns data, but that requires continuation.resume(returning:) and continuation.resuming(throwing:) on all locations returning the data or throwing an error. It feels easy to make a mistake somewhere and I don't really understand what the advantage is to writing the method with the continuation.

The advantage is that you can use await rather than having to pass a completion handler.  I would probably change your login function to be an async throwing function and have the else call resume(throwing:) rather than having it simply print the error

Pieter, does your app allow users to logout and log back in? I.e., might this closure ever be called more than once? If so, the withChecked[Throwing]Continuation pattern would not be correct. You might use an AsyncSequence, i.e., an AsyncStream, instead.

Yes, users can logout and log back in. I expect few users to actually do so but it definitely is something I want to account for in my code. Having not hears about AsyncSequence before I did a quick search, but it is not immediately apparent to me why I would want to use it in this case. It reads a bit like sequencing multiple async calls while only one async call is made, either to login or logout.

Actually, looking at the documentation, that closure appears to be a “one time only” completion handler, not a multi-event event handler, so a continuation does seem to make sense. The idea is that if you know a closure will be called once and only once, the continuation pattern makes sense (and using a “checked” continuation will verify that this is the case). If, however, the closure could be called multiple times (which does not appear to be the case here), then an asynchronous sequence would have been the right pattern.

Your attempt goes into the right direction. For the sake of readability, I'd recommend not doing anything other than calling the continuation in the callback handler, though, roughly like this:
func login() async {
    // Set the necessary configuration like client ID and redirect URI.
    // The config is also loaded.

    guard let authState = await authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: scene!.keyWindow!.rootViewController!) else {
        self.setAuthState(nil)
        return
    }
    self.setAuthState(authState)
    self.retrieveCookies()
}

/// performs authentication request
@MainActor // probably need to ensure we're on the MainActor, because a view controller is involved - might be unnecessary, if OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting:presenting:) somehow makes sure that the view controller is called on the main thread only
func authState(byPresenting request: Request, presenting viewController: UIViewController) async -> AuthState? {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        self.appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: viewController) { authState, error in 
            if let authState {
                print("Got authorization tokens!")
                continuation.resume(returning: authState)
            } else {
                print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                continuation.resume(returning: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

You could also think about using withThrowingContinuation, make the function async throws, and throw the provided error in the callback, then handle it at the call site, depending on what's best in your individual situation. I'd probably recommend doing that, but because the provided error is apparently optional, you'd need some kind of handling to tell what happens when both, authState and error are nil, so I skipped it here, for the sake of simplicity.
I'd also like to respond to your comment above:

It feels easy to make a mistake somewhere and I don't really understand what the advantage is to writing the method with the continuation.

The main advantage over callbacks (for me) is readability. While it may not make too much of a difference for a single callback based function call, imagine nested callbacks, when multiple async calls depend on each other and need to be run sequentially. Now compare that to simply using await on each line. Your code will still be just as readable, as if the calls were not async at all. With strict concurrency and Swift 6, more advantages in terms of compile-time safety for possible data races will come. Also the @MainActor attribute makes sure UI resources can only be accessed on the main thread, which again can prevent runtime issues at compile-time.

I second the vote for the throwing rendition, withCheckedThrowingContinuation. In an error can occur, then one should always throw it. If the caller doesn’t care, it can use try?. IMHO, we should never bake in “hide the error” behaviors.

Making the function async throws makes sense. As I find wrapping my head about asynchronous calls difficult I wanted to keep the focus on that instead of adding the subject of errors as well. Once I understand async calls better I want to move to sequential calls that depend on each other. Could you give a basic example of multiple calls that depend on each other to help illustrate the improved readability?

Doing this here in the comments seems tricky. I made a Gist to demonstrate a 3-step process with both approaches. https://gist.github.com/fabianmuecke/e9191eb36529788b6d798b19c4501ee1 I assumed here, that after obtaining an authState, the received cookies would be needed to fetch "models", whatever that might be. Compare the login() func with the login() async func to see the difference. I skipped error handling in both versions for simplicity. Please keep in mind that functions that are designed as async from the start won't need withCheckedThrowingContinuation.

I agree with fabianm (+1), that you should wrap this in a continuation. Personally, I would make it a throwing rendition, and I would put it in an OIDAuthState extension:
@preconcurrency import AppAuth

extension OIDAuthState {
    enum AuthError: Error {
        case unknown
    }

    static func authState(
        byPresenting request: OIDAuthorizationRequest,
        presenting viewController: UIViewController
    ) async throws -> OIDAuthState {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: viewController) { authState, error in
                guard error == nil, let authState else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error ?? AuthError.unknown)
                    return
                }

                continuation.resume(returning: authState)
            }
        }
    }
}

Then you can do things like:
func authenticate(_ authorizationRequest: OIDAuthorizationRequest) async throws {
    do {
        let state = try await OIDAuthState.authState(
            byPresenting: authorizationRequest,
            presenting: scene!.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
        )
        setAuthState(state)
        retrieveCookies()
    } catch {
        setAuthState(nil)
        logger.error("Error authenticating: \(error)")
    }
}

Now, the above presumes that OIDAuthState is thread-safe, but I have not seen any such assurances in the AppAuth docs, so you should presumably ask there or review the underlying code to make sure.
